# DetailsView Not Working with DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, detailsview

I am attempting to use a Details view.

This is my DataSource
[image]

I am passing it this way.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> row = Connection.GetDataTable([sql]).AsEnumerable();

this.dvOrderInformation.DataSource = row;
this.dvOrderInformation.DataBind();
```

I am binding it like so.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvOrderInformation" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="100%" AutoGenerateRows="false">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        Order
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <FieldHeaderStyle Width="150px" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order Number:" DataField="OrderID" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

When I try this I get the message.

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'OrderID'.
```

or

```
A field or property with the name 'OrderID' was not found on the selected data source.
```

If I bind this directly to a DataGrid it works fine.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
this.dvOrderInformation.DataSource = Connection.GetDataSet([sql]);
this.dvOrderInformation.DataBind()
```

The Key is that I must use a DataSet and not a DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust with

```
this.dvOrderInformation.DataSource = Connection.GetDataTable([sql]);
this.dvOrderInformation.DataBind();
```

Nota : it's normal row don't contain column, so he don't find column name

DataField="OrderID" is `DataColumn.Name`